# Time derivative of covariance terms

Tags: mathematical-statistics, stochastic-processes

I have a few covariance expressions for two correlated/dependent RVs like $\mathrm{Cov}(X',Y')=E[X'Y']$, where $X'=X-E[X]$, where $E[X]$ is the mean of $X$ and $X'$ is the fluctuation. I do not have any given densities associated with these RVs, I only know the nature of correlation either positive or negative. Now I want to derive the dynamical equations for covariance terms: i.e., I want to derive $\frac{\partial E[X'Y']}{\partial t}$. How will I do that?

I thought to use the Fokker-Planck equation, and for a try, I made assumptions as follows:

1. $X'$, $Y'$ have linear dynamics, i.e., $\frac{dX'}{dt}=k_X$ and $\frac{dY'}{dt}=k_Y$; where $k_Y$ and $k_X$ are some constants.
2. The diffusion coefficients $D_A$ and $D_B$ are constant. The FP equation then becomes

$$\frac{\partial P}{\partial t}=-k_X\frac{\partial(X'P)}{\partial X'}-k_Y\frac{\partial(Y'P)}{\partial Y'}+D_X\frac{\partial^2(P)}{\partial X'^2}+D_Y\frac{\partial^2(P)}{\partial Y'^2}$$ We are interested in $\frac{dE[X'Y']}{dt}$ and we know $E[X'Y']=\mathrm{Cov}(X',Y')$. Expressing $E[X'Y']$ in terms of joint probability:

$$E[X'Y']=\int X'Y'~P(X',Y',t)~dX'dY'$$
Then differentiating

$$\frac{d}{dt}E[X'Y']=\frac{d}{dt}\int X'Y'~P(X',Y',t)~dX'dY'$$

Then plugging the FP equation in this integral above.

$$\frac{d}{dt}E[X'Y']=\int X'Y'~[-k_X\frac{\partial(X'P)}{\partial X'}-k_Y\frac{\partial(Y'P)}{\partial Y'}+D_X\frac{\partial^2(P)}{\partial X'^2}+D_Y\frac{\partial^2(P)}{\partial Y'^2}]~dX'dY'$$

(assuming $\frac{d}{dt}\int A'B'PdA'dB'=\int A'B'\frac{d}{dt}P dA'dB'$ I'm not sure if it is actually allowed.. Maybe Leibnitz Rule?)

The issue is that I do not have a particular form of $P(X',Y',t)$, I only know a qualitative correlation between $X'$ and $Y'$. I want to ask whether this is the right approach? Or any other clues would be helpful.

My try is included in the question posed. I just wanted to know a clue and that whether I am on the right track.

Comment: It's unclear how you might possibly leverage a mere "qualitative correlation" into any kind of quantitative analysis.  It would help to understand what you do know and how you know it.

Comment: Thanks. The variables $X$ and $Y$ have a positive correlation, but I don't have an explicit form of it. Essentially $X$ is the population density and $Y$ is disease spread. It becomes more likely to have a disease spread with increasing population density.